# Laravel @include via ajax

Tags: php, laravel-5

Please somebody help me with an idea. How can I send `@include` blade via ajax?

It's something like this:

```
    @include('fronted.ajax.scripts.accavail',[
"accserviceid"=>base64_encode(serialize($accserviceid)),
"datasejur"=>base64_encode(serialize($data_sejur)),
"rateid"=>base64_encode(serialize($rateid))
])
```

If I insert the script directly in the blade, it's okay, but when I try to include it into blade it's not.

This blade sends and receives information via ajax post.

Comment: can you share the blade file too?

Comment: the blade is simple. if i put anything in blade not work wint include. the variable from include are send via ajax and al blade is send forward with ajax. It's strange because with i put in this blade the script from include file it's ok it's working but i wotn to insert via include.

Answer (score 0):

First you prepare a route which is dedicated to loading ajax content..

```
Route::get('/ajax/GetContent', array(
  'uses'  =>  'AjaxController@loadContent'
));
```

The controller in question basically loads content from the database (or whatever source you have), and returns html..
Now to the jquery part:

```
$(document).on('click','#nav', function(){
$.ajax({
    url: rootPath + '/ajax/GetContent',
    type: "GET", // not POST, laravel won't allow it
    success: function(data){
      $data = $(data); // the HTML content your controller has produced
      $('#container').fadeOut().html($data).fadeIn();    
      }
  });
});
```

I hope that was useful.. let me know if you need more..

Comment: It can be send and with post with condition to send the csrf token via ajax. The problem is in the interpretation of include I must to send it like string but I don't know how can I do this. In controller is simple I put (string) after return. Thanks a lot